# не запускается сервис при автозапуске

Tags: linux, c, service

написал для примера такую приколюху.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {

        daemon ( 0, 0 );
        for ( int i = 0; i < 99999; i++ ) {
                FILE *fp = fopen ( "/home/cf/file", "a" );
                fprintf ( fp, "st: %d\n", i );
                fclose ( fp );

                sleep ( 10 );
        }

}
```

и файл сервис.

```
[Unit]
Description=sst test
Requires=network-manager.service
After=network-manager.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/sst
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
Type=forking
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
Alias=sst.service
WantedBy=multiuser.target
```

если запускать так, systemctl start sst, то запускается. `systemctl enable sst` делал. я этот `sst.service` поместил в `/lib/systemd/system/`.
мне надо чтобы запустился сервис, после того, как включиться сеть. может надо что-то еще добавить. я пробовал вот так проверять `systemctl daemon-reload`, но сервис не запускался и я проверил на всякий случай, перезагрузив комп. всё равно не запускается или запускается и с ошибкой завершается. вообще не пойму. в инете примеры показаны и у них всё работает. а у меня нет.

Comment: Он у тебя не forking, а simple

Comment: Или функция демон его форкает?

Comment: @eri как функция daemon может форкнуть?

Comment: Я её не знаю) но больше тут ничего похожего нет... Так что сервис этот симпл

Comment: @eri что значит сервис simple, мне установить его надо или что?

Comment: Type=forking замени попробуй

Comment: функция daemon всегда форкает, *"запускается и с ошибкой завершается"* - с какой ошибкой?

Comment: @eri на что? я пробовал на oneshot, но тоже самое.

Comment: @user7860670 ну я думаю что с ошибкой. вообще пишет что innactive.